# NumberFormatException while parsing a Number

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
String str="123456.7855456677";
ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
NumberFormat numberFormat=new DecimalFormat();
Number number=numberFormat.parse(str, parsePosition);

if(parsePosition.getIndex()!=str.length())
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
double value=Double.parseDouble(numberFormat.format(number));
System.out.println(value);
```

The value of the String type variable `str` in this segment of code can be any dynamic value, assuming a user is free to input any string.

The `Double.parseDouble()` method on the **second last line** causes the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` to be thrown.

Removing the line `numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);` and setting a RegEx to the overloaded constructor of the `DecimalFormat` class instead as usual like,

```
NumberFormat numberFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

suppresses the exception.

So, why doesn't it work otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can debug the code then check out put of this line `numberFormat.format(number)` it gives a number containing a comma that might becoming reason for exception, check this `123,456.79` and this comma should not be there... hope this will help.

Comment: The input string is however `123456.7855456677`.

Comment: The original string `123456.7855456677` held by the String type variable `str` is represented as `Number` before parsing it to `Double`.

Comment: While scanning through the list of methods available in the `NumberFormat` class, I could see, it has to do something with grouping in a number, a number is by default represented in a group like 111,222,333. I have used `numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);` and the exception disappeared.

Comment: Thanks to both answers. It's actually one of my requirements in my web application using Spring/Hibernate where I'm implementing global converters. I have indeed  used the `NumberFormat#setGroupingUsed(boolean);` method once but accidently forgot that to use in this segment of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123,456.79"`
You cannot have a comma inside the string representation of double numbers.

Comment: The input string is however `123456.7855456677`.

Comment: No the input of the `Double.parseDouble` function is the result of `numberFormat.format(number)` which is `123,456.79`, which contains a comma and causes the exception